# Autocomplete, работа с JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Добрый день. У меня следующий вопрос: есть поле input с jquery autocomplete. Ниже - код обработки этого поля. Переменная `country-id`известна заранее.

```
$("#city-id").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "get-countries-cities.php",
            data: {
                "country-id": countryId,
                q: request.term
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function (rt) {
                    return {
                        title: rt.cities.title,
                        id: rt.cities.id
                    };
                }));
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert("Название города: " + ui.item.title + "id города: " + ui.item.id);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

С сервера приходит ответ в виде:

```
{
    "type":"success",
    "cities":[
        {
            "title":"Ишеевка, Пензенская область",
            "id":1068880
        },
        {
            "title":"Ишеевка, Ульяновская область",
            "id":1112050
        }
    ]
}
```

Далее я хочу, чтобы в поле input по нажатию оказалось название города (title), а в скрытом поле установилось значение id города (сейчас это дело эмулирует alert).

Беда в том, что я никак не могу "достучаться" до нужных мне элементов JSONа..
Что-то неверно здесь, полагаю.

```
return {
    title: rt.cities.title,
    id: rt.cities.id
};
```

P.S. В JS я вообще ноль. Но пришлось связаться. От количества {} и ({}) голова болит..

Comment: потому что в `map` надо отправлять не `data`, а `data.cities` внутри возвращать, `x.title` и `x,id`, мне правда почему-то помнится. что плагин требует пары `value` и `label`, но может и ошибаюсь. А `select` у вас почему то внутри вызова аякса. хотя относится к автокомплиту и должен быть на уровень выше.

Comment: @teran огромное спасибо! Когда читал документацию и проблемы других не думал, что value и label это обязательные названия..